# How to create Purchase Order in Netsuite with ScriptSuite?

Tags: netsuite, purchase-order, suitescript

I am new to Netsuite and I was asked to perform a script that was launched from an application programmed in java. The script with a function to generate a Purchase Order in Netsuite and other function to list the Purchase Order created earlier. It turns out that for this I am using the api SuiteScript but when creating the Purchase Order run the java application and launches the script but it gives the following error:

Aug 03, 2015 2:49:00 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient printContentIfNecessary
INFO: {"error": {"code": "user_error", "message": "Please enter value (s) for: Vendor"}}

Javascript function to create is:

```
function CreatePurchase_Orders(datain){

var output = '';
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','createRecord','ingreso la consulta' ) ;
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','createRecord', 'Ingresa: '+ datain);
//var msg = validateTimeBills(datain);
var msg = null;

if (msg){

    var err = new Object();
    err.status = "failed";
    err.message= msg;
    return err;
}

var Purchase_Orders = datain.Purchase_Order;
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','createRecord', 'obtuvo el objeto: '+ Purchase_Orders);

for (var Purchase_Orderobject in Purchase_Orders){

    var Purchase_Order = Purchase_Orders[Purchase_Orderobject];
    var transdate = Purchase_Order.Transdate;
    var Form = Purchase_Order.Form;
    var Vendor = Purchase_Order.Vendor;
    var Currency = Purchase_Order.Currency;
    var Item = Purchase_Order.Item;
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','campos','transdate: '+ transdate+'/Form: '+Form + ' /Vendor: ' + Vendor + ' /Currency: ' + Currency
                                                            + ' /Item: ' + Item);
    var Purchase_Order = nlapiCreateRecord('purchaseorder');
    var nlobjAssistant =   nlapiCreateAssistant ( 'asistente' , false ) ;

            var Purchase_Orderid =  1;//nlapiSubmitRecord( Purchase_Order , true, true);
            if(Purchase_Order){

                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Purchase_Order ' + Purchase_Orderid + ' successfully created', '');
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'createRecord', 'creo el record');

            }

    Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('transdate', transdate);
    Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('inpt_customform1', Form);
    Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('vendor', Vendor);
    Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('inpt_currency7', Currency);
    Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('inpt_item', Item);
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('quantity_formattedValue', '1');
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('rate_formattedValue', '1');
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('amount_formattedValue', '1');
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('inpt_taxcode', 'VAT_MX:UNDEF_MX');
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('grossamt_formattedValue', '1');
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('tax1amt_formattedValue', '0');
    Purchase_Order.setFieldText('expectedreceiptdate', '24/6/2015');

            //var Purchase_Orderid =  1;//nlapiSubmitRecord( Purchase_Order , true, true);                   
            var submitRecord = nlapiSubmitRecord(Purchase_Order);//,true);
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'submirRecord ' + submitRecord);

}

var mesg = new Object();
mesg.status = "OK";
mesg.message= nlobjAssistant.getAllFields();
return mesg;
```

}

And the function code in Java is:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_31);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(new URL(url),HttpMethod.POST);

        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Host", "rest.na1.netsuite.com");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("User-Agent", "SuiteScript-Call");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Language", " es-cl,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Referer", "http://localhost:8084");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Cookie", "");
        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

        requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Authorization", "NLAuth nlauth_account=" + account + ", nlauth_email=" + mail + ", nlauth_signature=" + pass + ", nlauth_role=" + role + "");

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        //objeto llenado estaticamente de forma momentanea, se debe leer desde archivo externo                    
        Purchase_Order purchaseOrder = new Purchase_Order("25/06/2015","formTest","vendorTest","CurrencyTest","itemTest");

        String cuerpo = gson.toJson(purchaseOrder);

        System.out.println(cuerpo);
```

//             Set the request parameters
            requestSettings.setRequestBody(cuerpo);

```
        Page page = client.getPage(requestSettings);
        WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();

        String json = response.getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(json);
```

With this javascript function you should create me a record Purchase Order but I can not find the error and the solution if someone could please help me I would appreciate it a lot.
PS: if you have to create a customized form could tell me how?
thanks!

Comment: Can you post your JSON structure to have an idea of the fields you're getting.

Comment: For now I'm using to test this:  {"Purchase_Order":[{"Transdate":"25/06/2015","Form":"formTest","Vendor":"vendorTest","Currency":"CurrencyTest","Item":"itemTest"}]}

Comment: Can you add some context to it. FYI, in order to create a PO you need to provide the internal id for the "vendor":`integer value` same applicable for the `item` also incase it is a Netsuite item.

Comment: In other words your json should be something like this : `{"Purchase_Order":[{"Transdate":"25/06/2015","Form":"101","Vendor":"102","Currency":"2","Item":"104"}]}`

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll try and commented that this is me. From already thank you very much for the clarification did not know.

Comment: If you've any concern feel free to post your quires. :)

Comment: these numbers must correspond to the internal id of vendor, form, currency and item? otherwise, as I can verify that the record was created ?? Greetings!

Comment: Yes, these numbers should correspond to their respective internal ids(vendor,form,currency & item)

Comment: I can not find the internal id in NetSuite, where I can get?

Comment: open the PO record and just click over the field name on the bottom of the pop up you can find the internal id of that field

Comment: thank you very much for the help, and I could do it. Now I could indicate some method to list all the Purchase Order created? Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here are some points :

As your error message says `Please enter value (s) for: Vendor`, you're missing the value for vendor field, which is mandatory. In your piece of code you're passing wrong `internalid` value for vendor. You should use `entity` instead of `vendor`

```
 Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('entity', Vendor); // where vendor is the internal id of the vendor record
```

For setting custom form you can use

```
Purchase_Order.setFieldValue('customform', Form); // where Form is the id of the custom form
```

I also noticed that you're setting some values in purchase order which I suspect are to be a kind of custom one. If that is the case, then your custom field internal id should be prefixed with `custbody`. 
For all the standard fields internal id you can refer to the Suite script [Records Browser.](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2014_1/script/record/purchaseorder.html)

Comment: friend thank you very much for the help, I am new to this and I'm a little tricky with what I requested. I will make the changes you propose and I commented that this was me. From already thank you very much!

Comment: As this work was uan leave without completing else I'm a little lost as I can verify the existence of the internal id of the fields to enter the Purchase Order form, maybe you better start from scratch. It might help with necessities? (creation of the form and everything you need to create Purchase Order, please.) I'll be attentive to comments.